# Unable to align buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm making a very simple UI and I have some buttons with different amounts of text. I need the buttons to have a set height and width. The problem is, when the text on the `button`s wraps, the button stops being aligned with the first one.

This is the simplest example I could come up with.

```css
button {
    height: 45px;
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<button>Short text</button>
<button>Text long enough to use two lines</button>
```

If you remove the `height` or `width` from the CSS, they are aligned again, but the sizes differ. I tried putting them in a container `div` and playing around with the `height`, `margin`, `padding` and stuff, but I couldn't fix it.

Question: **Is there another way of doing this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top` to your CSS rules:

```css
button {
    height: 45px;
    width: 120px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<button>Short text</button>
<button>Text long enough to use two lines</button>
```

The default vertical alignment is `baseline` so you would want to change this top top, or something similar to get the effect you want.